# ASP.NET dynamically adding UserControl and cache data on postbacks

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, user-controls

I have a Report.aspx page that loads different `UserControls` to view specific object data alternatively. The `UserControls` inherit the same base type class where override the specific operations methods. I use a specific Service class for each `UserControl` to get data which implements a specific interface with operations signatures.

I now use a factory pattern to return the actual `UserControl` type to the Report.aspx and load it into a `PanelControl`, then call the control method to fetch some data based on some arguments.

This `UserControl` should be loaded in every postback due to the dynamic nature of it, any other solution is accepted. On every postback though I don't need to load data from the BL which calls the DL. I try to find a solution to show to the BL that I don't need you to call for the data again because I'm just posting back for other issues (e.g. download a report file, print etc.). And I would like this to happen on the BL level, not the ASPX front end. So far I think that I should let BL somehow know this (PostBack or !PostBack). I guess I could just create a parameter true, false and pass the PostBack property.

Any ideas, architecture and best practices are so welcome.

Answer (score 0):

why not wrap the logic to call the BL inside the if(!Page.IsPostback){....} ?

Comment: This would not result in eficient caching strategy in the Business Layer. I need something to happen in the BL, maybe create a CL or something.

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate your statement "On every postback though I don't need to load data from the BL which calls the DL."?? During each postback, user control needs data to show (even if it is same data as last postback) because usercontrol goes through same lifecycle as ASPNET webpage. How can you prevent that?

Comment: That's right, thats what I'm searching for, how to load the UserControl again in the postback and prevent load data again from the data store. Basically the current problem is that the control is loaded programmaticaly, so it need to get loded in every postback, that means, load the data again, this is process consuming operation every time.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided that a very nice solution is System.Runtime.Caching in .NET 4.0.
Works very nice for every layer you need to use it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd985642